# Issues with innodb plugin

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have installed mysql 5.1.70 in Linux.

when I'm starting MySQL, I'm getting this

```
Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so'
```

Went to my.cnf and disabled innodb plugin. Mysql got started, but when I use innodb plugin variable in my.cnf file and start MySQL service, it throws more errors.

```
130923 23:06:03 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so' (errno: 22 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
130923 23:06:03 [ERROR] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb_plugin.so'.
130923 23:06:03 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--innodb_file_per_table'
130923 23:06:03 [ERROR] Aborting

130923 23:06:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

plugin does not exist in the directory

```
 [po@localhost plugin]$ ls -lrth /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so 
ls: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so: No such file or directory
```

How can i get this **/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so**?

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so` exist? If so, what are its permissions and ownership settings?

Comment: it is not exist [po@localhost plugin]$ ls -lrth /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so
ls: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so: No such file or directory
so how can i get this /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_innodb_plugin.so

Comment: Did you follow the directions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html? Also, why are you opting to use the plugin, instead of the builtin?